# dotnet publish not consuming appsettings.json

Tags: json, .net, .net-core, publish, appsettings

My .NET Core 2.1 app fails to read appsettings.json when I use `dotnet publish`. I've verified that appsettings.json *is* indeed copied to the out folder.

```
$ dotnet publish
$ cd the/publish/directory
$ ls -l

MyApp.dll
...
Other dlls
...
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Staging.json
runtimes/
web.config
wwwroot/
```

When I run `dotnet MyApp.dll` from the publish folder, none of my appsettings are loaded. Any ideas on why?

EDIT: appsettings IS consumed correctly in our Development environment.

Comment: Does it load app-settings inside the development environment?

Comment: Yes it does. And in our Staging environment (where we do *not* use dotnet publish)

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this inside your Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", 
                optional: true, 
                reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```